# Allow repository only for plugins?

Tags: java, maven, nexus

Can I restrict Maven to use a given Nexus repository (group) only to resolve plugins and their dependencies (and *not* for dependencies of the project itself)?

At the moment, I use a `settings.xml` which mirrors everything in a "public" group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <!--This sends everything to /public -->
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://ik-repo:8080/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>           
            <id>nexus</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Now I would like to use a second group "pluginPublic" (in addition to "public") that is used to resolve the dependencies of the plugins.

The background is as follows: I want to allow certain dependencies to be used by Maven plugins but not allow every developer to access them for their build.

Comment: Why is that tagged `java`?

Comment: Many maven plugins are tied to the java ecosystem, for example `cxf-codegen-plugin`. Tag seems relevant to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a mirror for everything but the plugin repository group:

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <!--This sends everything to /public -->
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*,!pluginpublic</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://ik-repo:8080/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>           
            <id>nexus</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>pluginpublic</id>
                    <url>http://ik-repo:8080/nexus/content/groups/pluginpublic/</url>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply set up the `pluginRepositores` in your `.m2/settings.xml`

```
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://my.company/repo</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://my.company/plugin_repo</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: What about mirrors? Can I define them separately for repositories and pluginRepositories? At the moment, I set a mirror that sends everything to the public group of my Nexus. I would like to have a second mirror for the plugins. Is this possible?

Comment: If you use a `mirror`, it doesnt seem possible to easily separate plugin and non-plugin artifacts in the `settings.xml` or `pom.xml`. Instead, you might be able to configure your nexus instance with three repositories: one for project dependencies, one for plugins (with an include pattern for `org.apache.maven.plugins` and a third one (which you mirror off of) which proxies both. But since I use artifactory I'm not sure if this is possible - you'd need to test it out.

Comment: But if I mirror by a group that proxies both, my Maven can still build projects against plugin dependencies, couldn't it?

Comment: Maven should build projects and deploy to the repository defined in `<distributionManagement>` -> `<repository>`

Comment: No, sorry if I was unclear. If I use the "public" group as a mirror (containing all repositories), then it can be used both for plugin dependencies and project dependencies. Even if I put different repositories into the <repositories> and <pluginRepositories> entries, these are probably overwritten by the mirror, so that these separate entries are useless.